# How to bind to the DataContext of a HierarchicalDataTemplate from its ItemTemplate XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, itemtemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

In my WPF TreeView, I have defined a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. In its `ItemTemplate`, there is a button whose `Command` I need to bind to the parent ViewModel, this is the `DataContext` of the parent `HierarchicalDataTemplate` or, in other words, the ViewModel which holds the collection `SubItems` in the example below. The `ItemTemplate`s own `DataContext` - the *SubItem* - is to be used as the `CommandParameter`.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">                
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="??CmdOnDtaCntxtOfHierDtaTmplt" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />                                 
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

How can this be done in XAML only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following binding should work:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Command, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

This will bind to the Command property of the DataContext (in your case the VM that holds the collection SubItems) associated to the TreeViewItem that is the parent of the current TreeViewItem.

Comment: It does work and is exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot!